# Printing an array defined by the user, first number determines the size of a word, second determines size of the row

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a loop that prints an array filled with letters, and prints them in a specific format determined by the user. The format is put in by the user in the command line, for example (not it also removes punctuation):

program.exe 5 8 "I'm trying to create a loop that prints an array filled with letters, and prints them in a specific"

```
imtry ingto creat ealoo pthat print sanar rayfi
lledw ithle tters andpr intst hemin aspec ific
```

I don't know how I'd create this loop. The array is 1 dimensional.

Edit: There seems to be some confusion here, I already have all the code, I just don't know how to implement spaces after the first number is met and create a new line after the second number is met. What I want to do is after every character is placed to check to see how many characters have been placed and then put in a space when appropriate, then increment another number forward. Once the second number is reached create a new line and set that number to 0.

Here's everything I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int wordSize = atoi(argv[1]) ;
    int rowSize = atoi(argv[2]) ;
    string test = argv[3] ;

    //Make vowels uppercase
    size_t found = test.find_first_of("aeiou");

    while (found!=string::npos)
    {
        if (islower(test[found])) ;
        {
            test[found] = toupper(test[found]) ;
            found=test.find_first_of("aeiou",found+1) ;
        }
    }

    //Make consonants lowercase
    size_t foundLower = test.find_first_of("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ") ;

    while (foundLower!=string::npos)
    {
        if (islower(test[foundLower])) ;
        {
            test[foundLower] = tolower(test[foundLower]) ;
            foundLower=test.find_first_of("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ",foundLower+1) ;
        }
    }

    //remove punctuation
    for (int i = 0, len = test.size(); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (ispunct(test[i]))
        {
            test.erase(i--, 1) ;
            len = test.size() ;
        }
    }

    //print the results in the blocks defined by the user
    //int size = (sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0])) ;
    for (int i = 0; i < wordSize; i++ )
    {
        //if (i = i / 5)
        //{
        //    cout << " " ;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    cout << test[i] ;
        //}
    }

    //while

    //cout << test << '\n' ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: array is two-dimensional? if not you can use for loop e.g. int i=arr[0], this is for words , and int size= arr[1] can be used for size

Comment: I'm afraid we expect you to make a little more of an effort before posting a question here. Just stating a problem and saying "I don't know how to do it" is not enough. Reread your text books and class notes, and solve some simpler problems until you get a better understanding of the language, and then make your best effort at solving this. Come back when you hit a specific problem for which you cannot find any information anywhere else.

Comment: I'll leave the exact implementation up to you, since we don't generally write code for you here. But look into `argc` for making sure the user passed you the right number of command-line flags, `argv` for accessing those command-line flags, and `std::string` (specifically its `substr` method) and `std::vector` for splitting the input up into blocks.

Comment: This isn't a class project and this is a specific problem. I don't know how to create this loop. What I'd like to do is input a space after the first number is met (the limit to the word size) and then create a new line after the second number is met (the limit for the row), I already have everything done except the loop. I have the variables, I have the array, just not the loop.

Comment: Mind posting your code in the question, then? If you can show you've worked on this and made some progress, I'll help you out more with the loop.

Comment: I posted it in the OP.

Comment: Oh wow, you _are_ almost there. Okay, I'll post an answer shortly. +1 in the meantime to balance your downvotes, I doubt you would've gotten downvoted at all if you'd posted the code when you first asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I made a few minor fixes to some of your code, and left comments explaining what I fixed and why (all I recall at the moment is a couple of semicolons after `if` statements - you don't want those there!)

The loop is the answer to your question. It breaks down the input using `substr`, or substring, and prints it. There are also some basic sanity checks to make sure we can keep calling `substr` with a full word size and still keep iterating afterward. There's also a rolling counter that counts how many words we printed and prints an `endl` at the appropriate point.

It's also worth pointing out that, as the code stands right now, the command window will close immediately after printing everything. You might want to put a `system("pause");` or `getch();` at the end so it won't close right away.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int wordSize;
  int wordCounter = 0;
  int rowSize;
  string test;

  if (argc < 4) //make sure we got all the parameters we needed; the code will crash without them
  {
    cout << "Error: not enough parameters";
    return 1;
  }

  wordSize = atoi(argv[1]);
  rowSize = atoi(argv[2]);
  test = argv[3];

  //Make vowels uppercase
  size_t found = test.find_first_of("aeiou");

  while (found != string::npos)
  {
    if (islower(test[found])) //minor fix here, you don't want the semicolon!
    {
      test[found] = toupper(test[found]);
      found = test.find_first_of("aeiou", found + 1);
    }
  }

  //Make consonants lowercase
  size_t foundLower = test.find_first_of("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ");

  while (foundLower != string::npos)
  {
    if (islower(test[foundLower])) //another removed semicolon here
    {
      test[foundLower] = tolower(test[foundLower]);
      foundLower = test.find_first_of("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ", foundLower + 1);
    }
  }

  //remove punctuation
  for (int i = 0, len = test.size(); i < len; i++)
  {
    if (!isalnum(test[i])) //we can't test for punctuation with ispunct, because spaces get through
    {
      test.erase(i--, 1);
      len = test.size();
    }
  }

  while (!test.empty())
  {
    if (test.length() < wordSize) //make sure we don't go out-of-bounds
    {
      wordSize = test.length();
    }

    cout << test.substr(0, wordSize);
    cout << " ";

    if (test.length() >= wordSize) //again, make sure we don't go out-of-bounds
    {
      test = test.substr(wordSize);
    }
    else
    {
      test = "";
    }

    wordCounter++;
    if (wordCounter == rowSize)
    {
      cout << std::endl;
      wordCounter = 0;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. I was planning on adding an error check as well so thank you for that.

Comment: No problem. The error checks are actually necessary; most runs will end in crashes due to off-by-one errors without them. `substr` isn't forgiving of out-of-bounds start positions.